# MapWinGis WindowsForms C# : Point and Polygon

Tags: c#, polygon, shapes, mapwingis

I’m new to MapWinGis, and i would like to make a project which consists in placing points on the map, to draw the polygon according to the placed points except that I manage only to draw the polygon, no point is displayed. I try to add shape for point and polygon, what i’m doing wrong ? Thank you very much !
[The result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ8H5.png)

```
namespace test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    bool flagNewShp, flagDgvValid;
    Shape shp = new Shape();
    Shape shpPoint = new Shape();
    Shapefile sf = new Shapefile();
    Shapefile sfPoint = new Shapefile();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        axMap1.CursorMode = tkCursorMode.cmNone;

        axMap1.SendMouseDown = true;
        axMap1.MouseDownEvent += AxMap1_MouseDownEvent;

        dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Clear();
        dgvCoordonnees.Columns.Clear();

        dgvCoordonnees.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgvCoordonnees.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dgvCoordonnees.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
        dgvCoordonnees.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        dgvCoordonnees.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        dgvCoordonnees.RowHeadersVisible = false;

        dgvCoordonnees.Columns.Add("Point", "Point");
        dgvCoordonnees.Columns.Add("Lat", "Lat");
        dgvCoordonnees.Columns.Add("Lon", "Lon");
    }



    private void AxMap1_MouseDownEvent(object sender, _DMapEvents_MouseDownEvent e)
    {





        if (e.button == 1)
        {

            if (flagNewShp == true)
            {
                flagNewShp = false;
                shp.Create(ShpfileType.SHP_POLYGON);
                shpPoint.Create(ShpfileType.SHP_POINT);
                sf.CreateNew("", ShpfileType.SHP_POLYGON);
                sfPoint.CreateNew("1", ShpfileType.SHP_POINT);
                flagDgvValid = true;
            }
            else
            {


                double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;
                axMap1.PixelToProj(e.x, e.y, ref x, ref y);

                shpPoint.AddPoint(x, y);
                shp.AddPoint(x, y);

                axMap1.PixelToDegrees(e.x, e.y, ref x, ref y);
                double latitude = y;
                double longitude = x;
                if (flagDgvValid == true)
                {
                    dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Add();
                    dgvCoordonnees[0, dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Count - 1].Value =                   dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Count;
                    dgvCoordonnees[1, dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Count - 1].Value = latitude;
                    dgvCoordonnees[2, dgvCoordonnees.Rows.Count - 1].Value = longitude;
                }


                sf.EditAddShape(shp);
                sfPoint.EditAddShape(shpPoint);

                ShapeDrawingOptions optionsPoint = sfPoint.DefaultDrawingOptions;

                optionsPoint.PointType = tkPointSymbolType.ptSymbolStandard;
                optionsPoint.PointShape = tkPointShapeType.ptShapeCross;

                sfPoint.CollisionMode = MapWinGIS.tkCollisionMode.AllowCollisions;
                sf.CollisionMode = MapWinGIS.tkCollisionMode.AllowCollisions;

                ShapeDrawingOptions options = sf.DefaultDrawingOptions;

                options.PointSize = 100;
                options.FillVisible = true;
                options.FillColor = new Utils().ColorByName(tkMapColor.LightPink);
                options.FillTransparency = 100;
                options.LineColor = new Utils().ColorByName(tkMapColor.Black);
                options.LineWidth = 1;

                MessageBox.Show($"Nombre de points : {shp.numPoints}");
                MessageBox.Show($"Nombre de points : {shpPoint.numPoints}");


                axMap1.AddLayer(shp, true);
                axMap1.AddLayer(sf, true);   
                axMap1.AddLayer(sfPoint, true);
                axMap1.AddLayer(shpPoint, true);

                axMap1.Redraw();
                //axMap1.CurrentZoom = 11;

            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        axMap1.Latitude = 46.827282F;
        axMap1.Longitude = 8.227511F;
        axMap1.CurrentZoom = 7;

    }

    private void btnNewShape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flagNewShp = true;
    }


}
```

I would like to have points and polygon like the result.
Thanks you for the help !